# Excel - Using a word located in a different cell, into a SUMIFS formula using exact match

Tags: excel, sumifs, exact-match

I am looking to use a SUMIFS formula that can use a word typed into a different cell, so if the word were to be changed later, it would also update the formula automatically.

Here is an example:

> **CELL A -** Apple
>
> **CELL B -** Banana
>
> **CELL C -** Orange

Here is the formula I am using right now:

```
=SUM((SUMIFS($X:$X,$Y:$Y,"Apple")*0.5)+(SUMIFS($X:$X,$Y:$Y,"Banana")*0.75)+(SUMIFS($X:$X,$Y:$Y,"Orange")*1.25))
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```
=SUM((SUMIFS($X:$X,$Y:$Y,"CELL[A]")*0.5)+(SUMIFS($X:$X,$Y:$Y,"CELL[B]")*0.75)+(SUMIFS($X:$X,$Y:$Y,"CELL[C]")*1.25))
```

I hope this makes sense!  I am still very new to here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is accomplished easily by directly referencing a range (specially if that range is static, as is mostly the case):

```
=SUM((SUMIFS($X:$X,$Y:$Y,A1)*0.5)+(SUMIFS($X:$X,$Y:$Y,A2)*0.75)+(SUMIFS($X:$X,$Y:$Y,A3)*1.25))
```

And then, in A1,A2 and A3, you have control cells for your conditional sum.

Is there any special reason to  do sumifs when you are only testing for one criteria ?